# Ubuntu install hangs on third menu

Tags: system-installation, 15.10, troubleshooting, usb-installation

I am attempting to install Ubuntu 15 onto another desktop of mine. I currently have it installed on three other computers. The problem that I am having is that during the installation set up the program freezes and is unable to continue. The computer doesn't freeze as I can still move around and do other processes, however the installation set up refuses to continue, and catches after the third screen. This is the menu screen when it asks if I want to install third party programs and updates while installing. Any help diagnosing the issues or potentially solving it would be much appreciated. And I have run the memory check, and the hardware check, and there doesn't seem to be any errors that occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ideas:

Is your boot CD/Pendrive correct? 
 (try the option "Check disc for defects")

Are your network settings right? 
 (Try F2 and "ping google.com")

Comment: It determined to have two file defects, so after using a different use it seems to have worked Thanks

Answer (score 0):

say yes. Make sure you are connected to wired LAN connection if you are saying yes. As this will require internet connection. In case your wireless connection is already working then no worries.

Comment: Yes the wireless is working fine, as before I begin the installation process, I am able to run without installing, and using chrome, and any other programs. That is how I have been using it just through the installation flash drive.

Comment: then go ahead...chose yes